# Android Support Annotations - How to use IntDef/StringDef (Typedef Annotations) with generics list?

Tags: java, android, generics, annotations

Recently I started using android's support library IntDef/StringDef (Typedef Annotations). I followed the documentation in [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations) and couldn't find there or in any other relevant tutorial how can I use IntDef/StringDef typedef annotations with generics array. for example, assuming I have the following code snippet:

```
public static final String MEDIA_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String MEDIA_TEXT = "text";
public static final String MEDIA_LINK = "link";
public static final String MEDIA_AUDIO = "audio";
public static final String MEDIA_VIDEO = "video";
public static final String MEDIA_VOICE = "voice";

@StringDef ({MEDIA_IMAGE, MEDIA_TEXT, MEDIA_LINK, MEDIA_AUDIO, MEDIA_VIDEO, MEDIA_VOICE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Media {}
```

I would like to do something similar to this using generics array and typedef annotations:

```
public List<@Media String> getMediaItems() {
    ...
}

public void setMediaItems(List<@Media String> mediaItems) {
    ...
}
```

However, that seems to be impossible that way.. Since the compiler says:

> "Type annotations are not supported at this language level"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

There is no way you can annotate type parameters in Java - the language does not support this. The only thing you can do with type parameters - is make them [bounded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: So in practice StringDef typedef annotation is useless with collections?  should I rather use enums instead?

Comment: @MaximRahlis yes, I suppose enums are your only choice if you want to make sure on compile time that your collection contains only valid values.

Comment: @aga Note that the JLS does actually show that annotations on type arguments of parameterized types are allowed: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1

Comment: @adelphus this is true for the 8-th edition of JLS, the same chapter in the 7-th edition of JLS does not mention annotations in type arguments (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1). Android supports only Java 7, so it's safe to say that Java on Android does not allow them - at least for now.

Comment: When I first read it I thought here comes a nice alternative to enums benefits :( . After all using enums especially in android is controversial.

Comment: @adelphus I researched this a little bit and it looks like the type annotations are a part of JSR 308 (http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-design.pdf) which is part of Java SE 8. So yes, there is no opportunity to use them on Android.

Comment: Though Java 8 is not officialy supported in android (and one may have few issues), I already used jdk 8 to compile android projects. I will check it tomorrow morning to see if it passes the compiler with jdk 8..

Comment: @MaximRahlis well, you can compile your projects using JDK 8, but you can not use new language features added in Java 8 (like lambdas, or type annotations for example) in your project. these new features have to be added to JVM which you use to run your apps. Dalvik/ART does not have support of Java 8 features, so you can not run the code that uses them on these JVMs.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I finally checked it with Java 8 and it works as long as I use @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) I suppose. So practically It is possible. But because I have other problems I encountered with Java 8, I will keep on using Java 7 for Android and will wait patiently for Android to support Java 8 or other language alternative :)

Answer (score 2):

If you try to do something like `private List<@Media String> mList` with `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` you'll get a

> Type annotation are not supported at this language level

Though you can do something like `private @Media String[] mArray`.
With `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` `private @Media List<String> mList` will work.

I'll be honest, didn't run to test it, but no Lint error was given.